# How to display video through Logitech Quickcam Express (V-UH9)

Tags: usb, camera

I am trying to setup my very old Logitech Quickcam Express (V-UH9) using motion. When I run motion, I see on the local ip address a grey box, with time and text being displayed (according to the specification in motion.conf), but the image is non-transparent grey. I also get the following error:

```
[0] Processing thread 0 - config file /etc/motion/motion.conf
[0] Motion 3.2.12 Started
[0] ffmpeg LIBAVCODEC_BUILD 3482368 LIBAVFORMAT_BUILD 3478785
[0] Thread 1 is from /etc/motion/motion.conf
[0] motion-httpd/3.2.12 running, accepting connections
[0] motion-httpd: waiting for data on port TCP 8070
[1] Thread 1 started
[1] cap.driver: "spca561"
[1] cap.card: "Camera"
[1] cap.bus_info: "usb-bcm2708_usb-1.3"
[1] cap.capabilities=0x85000001
[1] - VIDEO_CAPTURE
[1] - READWRITE
[1] - STREAMING
[1] Config palette index 8 (YU12) doesn't work.
[1] Supported palettes:
[1] 0: S561 (S561)
[1] 1: GBRG (GBRG)
[1] Unable to find a compatible palette format.
[1] ioctl (VIDIOCGCAP): Inappropriate ioctl for device
[1] Could not fetch initial image from camera
[1] Motion continues using width and height from config file(s)
[1] Resizing pre_capture buffer to 1 items
[1] Started stream webcam server in port 8071
[1] Retrying until successful connection with camera
```

From my little experience with linux I read from this that the camera not recognised. Querying 'dmesg less' results in (what I think is the relevant part):

```
[    3.267362] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[    3.394213] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=0928
[    3.409447] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    3.429015] usb 1-1.3: Product: Camera
[    3.434406] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer:         
[    3.958265] udevd[156]: starting version 175
[    5.416909] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    5.534918] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    5.757727] gspca_main: v2.14.0 registered
[    5.959040] gspca_main: spca561-2.14.0 probing 046d:0928
[    6.082778] bcm2708-i2s bcm2708-i2s.0: Failed to create debugfs directory
[    6.207869] input: spca561 as /devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/input/input0
[    6.517440] usbcore: registered new interface driver spca561
```

I have a different camera (PS3 eye), which is running perfectly so the basic set up seems ok. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

write this string in header of your  /etc/init.d/motion file :

export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so

check this thread for more
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/webcam_setup#Get_software_to_use_your_webcam

you can have a different place for this lib, use :

locate v4l1compat.so